# '$' is undefined error in react app running in IE 11

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, babeljs

how do i get rid of error '$' is undefined in IE 11 ? I am using react with typescript (traget es2015). Babel configuration in webpack config looks like this

```
         test: /\.(tsx|ts)$/,
                loader: "awesome-typescript-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    "useBabel": true,
                    "babelOptions": {
                        "babelrc": false, /* Important line */
                        "presets": [
                            '@babel/preset-env',
                            "@babel/preset-react"
                        ],
                        "plugins": [
                            [
                                "@babel/plugin-transform-classes", { "loose": true }
                            ],
                            [
                                "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator", { "asyncGenerators": false, "generators": false, "async": false }
                            ],
                            [
                                "@babel/plugin-transform-parameters"
                            ],
                            [
                                "@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping"
                            ],
                            [
                                "@babel/plugin-transform-typeof-symbol"
                            ]
                        ]
                    },
                    "babelCore": "@babel/core"
                }
```

Comment: That's typically an error related to jquery. Are you using any jQuery code?

Comment: it looks like the script i import does, it fails on this line $(function(){"use strict";var t,n,i,r;$.each(

Comment: That is probably where the problem is. You can either import the jquery library (not recommended with react), or use a library that doesn't require it.

Comment: this script is crucial and i cannot exclude it.

Comment: Then import the jquery library...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in googleapi maps script. I got an string expected error due to polyfills and that caused another errors.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.